# DNS and Namerservers query

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, spf

I have a VPS hosted with 1&1 which also provides mailboxes that we use for day to day e-mailing. Our domain is registered with 123reg and the name servers point to 1&1 .

To email our 10k+ mailing list I use Amazon SES and I wish to validate against our domain
. Now I cant verify my email with amazon as 1&1 doesn't support TXT/SPF however 123reg does.

My question is ( and my apologies for my lack of DNS knowledge ) can change the name servers  back to 123reg and then create A/CNAME/MX records to point to 1and1 for my mail and webhosting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use two approaches to solve this problem.

1) you may try to install and configure the DNS server on your VPS host, and setting up manually your zones will give you the flexibility to setup any record you may need, such as TXT/SPF records.

2) you can switch back your DNS servers to 123reg and setup the MX record to point to your 1&1 mail server and allow, through your TXT/SPF record the Amazon SES server to send e-mails on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to you domain provider they can do that for you I believe. I just had to do something of the same sort.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, any domain registrar which doesn't provide you with the ability to add TXT/SPF records is not worth it. Switch to the one which will provide you with as many features of dns as possible, and the ease of modifying your domains on your own without contacting their support or not being told it is not possible.It should not be difficult to change your name servers back to 123reg, and replicate all the dns records you have in 1&1 there (A/CNAME/MX as well as TXT/SPF....).

Plan this switching when your site is least busy, and try to lower the TTL value for a quick update.